# XYMon-Client status not showing in XYMon Server

Tags: networking, monitoring

I have installed XYMon server successfully, **but I can't get the client information to show**. It took me a while to figure out, but if you add a host to the server that doesn't have the client, it still shows some things like conn/ssh/info, but nothing like cpu/disk/mem.

I have found it to be REALLY hard to find any good documentation, troubleshooting steps or anything. The installation of the client seems extremely simple.

On **Ubuntu 14.04** >>

```
apt-get install xymon-client
```

Only one question during installation

IP of XYMon-Server

But I can't get anything to show in the server!

The closest I have come to debugging is

On Server :

```
@xymon:/var/log/xymon$ cat alert.log

2016-07-20 21:31:52 ->  Could not connect to Xymon daemon@xymon.freesoftwareservers.com:1984 (Connection refused)

@xymon:/var/log/xymon$ cat xymonlaunch.log

2016-07-20 22:00:27 Cannot open env file /usr/local/xymon/server/etc/hobbitserver.cfg - No such file or directory
2016-07-20 22:00:27 Loading hostnames
2016-07-20 22:00:27 Loading saved state
2016-07-20 22:00:27 Setting up network listener on 0.0.0.0:1984
2016-07-20 22:00:27 Setting up signal handlers
2016-07-20 22:00:27 Setting up xymond channels
2016-07-20 22:00:27 Setting up logfiles
2016-07-20 22:10:27 Cannot open env file /usr/local/xymon/server/etc/hobbitserver.cfg - No such file or directory
```

**On Both Client & Server I found this Error :**

```
@xymon:/var/log/xymon$ cat xymonclient.log 
No LSB modules are available. - Repeated for ever...
```

There was nothing more useful in client logs.

**Install XYMON Config :**

```
sudo apt-get install -y xymon
sudo cp /etc/apache2/conf.d/xymon /etc/apache2/conf-available/xymon.conf
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/conf-available/xymon.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/authz_groupfile.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/cgi.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
sudo ln -s /var/lib/xymon /var/www/html/xymon
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/xymon.conf
```

*Replace the below 2 lines with the bottom ONE line. (All instances)*

```
#Order allow,deny
#Allow from localhost ::1/128
Require all granted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on This [page from XYMon regarding Clients not reporting](http://xymon.sourceforge.net/xymon/help/xymon-tips.html#noclient) I figured it out. While it gives the problem, I couldn't get the solutions there to work.

**On Client :**

```
cat /etc/default/xymon-client | grep CLIENTHOSTNAME
```

**Must Match on Server :**

```
/etc/xymon/hosts.cfg

1.2.3.4 CLIENTHOSTNAME
```

If it doesn't **match EXACTLY** then >>

"Xymon only cares about the hosts that are in the hosts.cfg file, and discards status-reports from unknown hosts"

Comment: Note, I was able to change CLIENTHOSTNAME and then change hosts.cfg and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xymon-client` on your client and insert the exact hostname as you wrote it in your hosts.cfg on your server.

Comment: This is the "ubuntu/debian" way to fix it, but its always good to know what "dpkg-reconfigure" is doing!, I expect most people using xymon have both Debian and RHEL based clients, and `/etc/default/xymon/` is import to know, but def +1 for the simple debian answer